# How do I attach an event handler to an ASP.NET control created at runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

Good morning everybody.

I have a question connected with controls and event handling. Lets say I want to create a `LinkButton`.

```
protected void loadLinkButton()
{
    ContentPlaceHolder content = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("MainContent");
    LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
    lnk.ID = "lnikBtn";
    lnk.Text = "LinkButton";
    lnk.Click += new System.EventHandler(lnk_Click);
    content.Controls.Add(lnk);
}
```

Here is the event handler:

```
protected void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "ok!";
}
```

If I run the `loadLinkButton` function inside `Page_Load` everything is ok.  But when I try to run the `loadLinkButton` by clicking simple button, link button is created but event is not handled.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loadLinkButton();
}
```

I there any way to solve it? Or loadLinkButton must always regenerated on `Page_Load`, `Page_init` etc.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing dynamic about this code.  I'm somewhat disappointed that the people answering this question are encouraging that terminology.

Comment: @Aaronaught - What exactly would you call it? Adding controls programatically has long been called ***dynamically*** adding controls. Almost any forum, user group, or blog you go to will use the same terminology...

Comment: @Josh: It's long been *incorrectly* called that, yes.  I don't begrudge the OP for being confused but high-reputation answerers shouldn't be repeating the term.  The word "dynamic" only makes any sense when contrasted against *static* (i.e. dynamically-linked library, [dynamic typing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)) or when referring to [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata).  This question is referring to the difference between controls created at *design time* vs. *runtime*, as I've indicated in the edits.

Comment: @Aaronaught - I understand the academic side of the argument, but a common nomenclature has been adopted amongst practitioners of many different languages and platforms in regards to things done at runtime. 99 out of 100 people you talk to will understand what you mean when you say **"dynamically added"** or **"dynamic controls."** At that point the strict syntax of the word doesn't really matter anymore. Much the same as when someone says "Cool!" they aren't usually talking about temperature.

Comment: @Josh: I fully understand that English itself is not a formal language with rules prescribed by academics, but computer languages and frameworks actually **are** formally defined by specifications and a word does not become correct because a lot of people misuse it (e.g. [Agile](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2005-11-16/)). It's particularly important to be correct in *this* case because the word "dynamic" **already means something different** in C#, and that's what the `[dynamic]` tag is supposed to be used for.

Comment: In this trivial example you would be better of declaring the button in the markup and show/hide it by manipulating the `Visible` property rather than giving yourself the headache of programatically creating controls.

Comment: Hello everybody. Using the word "dynamic" arise due to the lack of insufficient experience in C# programming. As Josh suggested better expression is "controls created at runtime".

Comment: @Aaronaught, I completely agree and understand the discussion over the 'dynamic' word. I do not agree to the point that the word  'dynamic' is incorrect in terms of programming language for this particular case. The word is being used in expression from the English language (dynamic control) not by its meaning in the C# language. Furthermore, the term has arisen long before MS intoduced the `dynamic` keyword. Still, I completely approve the removal of the [dynamic] tag as it was indeed misused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with dynamic controls, I always add the control in **Page_Init**, because viewstate loading will happen right after Init. If you add it to Page_Load, there is a chance that you will lose viewstate. Just make sure you provide a unique control ID.

Comment: `Page_Load` is usually too late to add controls and have them respond to postback events; `Page_Init` is the better place and you will need to recreate the control every postback.  Creating controls in `Button1_Click` will almost certainly lead to headaches.

Answer (score 3):

It is important to know how ASP.Net determines which events to invoke. The source of each event is passed using a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
```

Whenever the page loads, it pulls in the source of the event from that field and then determines which event to invoke. Now this all works great for controls added through markup because the entire control tree is regenerated on every request.

However, your control was only added once. When a Postback occurs, your control no longer exists as a Server control in the tree, and therefore the event never fires.

The simply way to avoid this is to **make sure your Dynamic Controls are added every time** the page loads, either through the `Page_Init` event, or the `Page_Load` event.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. This is the expected behavior. Page_Load and Page_Init would be the events where you should be adding it.

Answer (score 0):

That would be because when you click your dynamically generated linkbutton, you do a postback to the server. There you do an entirely new pageload, but your original buttonclick (that generates the link) never happened now, so the linkbutton is never made, and the event can not be thrown.

An alternative is to add the linkbutton you add dynamically, to your page statically, with Visible = false. And when you click the other button, make it visible.

Answer (score -1):

I am not exactly sure what problem you are facing but you should put the dynamic controls code in Page_Init as suggested by @johnofcross:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateControls();
        }

        private void CreateControls()
        {
            var lb = new LinkButton();
            lb.Text = "Click Me";
            lb.Click += lb_Click;

            ph.Controls.Add(lb);
            ph.DataBind();
        }

        void lb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Button is clicked!"; 
        }
    }
```