# Cannot access the CSS class for a link button from Code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

Can we include a CSS class from code behind for a link button?

I have been trying this for a while, but I was not able to get it done. It does not show a hyper link nor does CSS work. Please refer to my code and see where am I doing wrong.

```
string link1 = "google.com"
lblclick.Text = "<p>See what our page looks like by clicking " 
+ "<asp:LinkButton CssClass="+"linkclass" + ">" 
+ link1 + "</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to add a linkbutton to a panel from codebehind you will have to create it from code.

```
LinkButton lb = new LinkButtton();
lb.cssclass="linkclass";
lb.text = "foo";
panel1.Controls.Add(lb);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just add ASP.NET markup as a textproperty in your code, ASP doesn't work like that. Create a `Linkbutton btn = new LinkButton()`, and add it: `lblclick.Controls.Add(btn)`. Then you can edit the properties of `btn` as you please.

Answer (score 1):

Create the `LinkButton` in code like this:

```
LinkButton linkButton = new LinkButton();
linkButton.CssClass = "linkclass";
linkButton.Text = "google.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

If lblclick is a `Label`, then you can't add a asp tag like LinkButton just like that.

If you can (or if you move the LinkButton to your markup) you need to add the `runat="server"` to be able to set properties like `CssClass` on it. If you just want a plain link you can add an anchor tag instead.

```
lblclick.Text = "<p>See what our page looks like by clicking 
<a href=\"" + link + "\" class=\"linkclass\">" + link1 + "</a></p>"
```

---

Actually, if you want a *link* to another page you shouldn't use LinkButton at all, but rather the [HyperLink class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx). You can use the [NavigateUrl property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.navigateurl.aspx) to set the url to open when clicking the link.

If you want to add it to your markup you do it like this

```
<asp:HyperLink
     NavigateUrl="http://www.example.com"
     CssClass="linkclass"
     Text="link1"
     runat="server" />
```

and if you want to do it dynamically in code you add it by creating it and adding it to your `Controls` collection.

```
HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
link.NavigateUrl = "http://www.example.com";
link.Text = "link1";
link.CssClass = "linkclass";
Controls.Add(link);
```

Just remember that when you add controls dynamically you should add it in your `Page_Load` event every time you load your page. If you don't want it to display set its `Visible` property to `false` and change it to `true` based on an event or something. Perhaps not as important when using a HyperLink, but good practice nonetheless. An example of when dynamic controls bite you if you don't is [this question asked recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145851/asp-net-c-creating-dynamicly-controls-handling-events).