# Attaching a click event onto an image within a grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having trouble attaching a click event onto an image that I have stored within a grid view.  Basically it is a delete button that will allow the user to delete a specific row depending on where the button is.  I have the code in c# ready for it, however, I cannot seem to attach a click event to it.

This is the markup code of the button

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remove" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbDeleteP" runat="server" BORDER="0" CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl="~/img/Del.png" Height="25px" ImageAlign="Middle"
                               onClick ="gv_Quals_RowCommand" CommandArgument="<%#Container.DataItemIndex%>" CommandName="Remove" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
```

> onClick ="gv_Quals_RowCommand"

Here is the code in c# for the click event

```
protected void gv_Quals_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.CommandName == "Remove"))
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow row = gv_Quals.Rows[index];
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)Session["CurrentTable"];
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[index].Delete();
            if ((dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count < 0))
            {

            }
            else if ((row.Cells[0].Text != "*New*"))
            {
                int appId = 5000;
                //int appId = 1;
                string insProg = ("delete from projectunitassignment where UnitId =" + int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Text));
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insProg, conn);
                cmd.Connection.Close();
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Connection.Close();
                RebindCat(appId);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the compilation error that I keep getting

**CS0123: No overload for 'gv_Quals_RowCommand' matches delegate 'ImageClickEventHandler'**

I cannot set the click event through the properties as it is stored within the grid view so I cannot access it through there.  Also the click event does not run as I have tested with debugging

Comment: I think that is because of `GridViewCommandEventArgs` which commonly used for `RowCommand` , change it to `EventArgs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `GridViewCommandEventArgs` should be just `EventArgs`

```
public void imgbDeleteP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

**Edit:**

> I see that in your code you use the Command Argument, so if you want to use that you should see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676618/e-commandargument-for-asp-button-is-not-working)
>
> Basically use `onCommand` instead of `onClick` or cast the sender to button to get the command argument, something like:

```
var argument = ((ImageButton)sender).CommandArgument;
```

Comment: else you can follow @Aria Answer

Comment: I just changed it to CommandArgument and now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to associate the click event for that grid during page load ?

Comment: I do not know what you mean, can you display an example?

Comment: Check this out "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145851/how-do-i-attach-an-event-handler-to-an-asp-net-control-created-at-runtime"

Comment: nah I cant.  The buttons within the grid view so I cant access it through the id unless I find the control.

Comment: Try sending the id as a one of the arguments, that way you may have more control as well

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because of `GridViewCommandEventArgs` which commonly used for `RowCommand` , change it to `EventArgs`, so that event should be something like this:

```
protected void gv_Quals_RowCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;
     string cmName= btn.CommandName;
     string cmArgument= btn.CommandArgument;
     if ((cmName == "Remove"))
     {
        ..... 
     }
}
```

or to get row index:

```
GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
int index = gvRow.RowIndex;
```

The first parent is the `GridView` Cell and the second parent of the `GridView` Cell is the GridView Row.